# Why am I receiving an empty string as data in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass a string id to a function, located in another file, but as a response from that function, all I get is an empty string. If a invoke the function again, then the ID is displayed. The function I'm talking about is in the second .then - getMatchHistory(). Here is my code:

```
  axios
      .get(`https://${region}.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/${summonerName}?api_key=${API_KEY}`)
      .then((response) => {
        setError("");
        setUser(response.data);
        setName(response.data.name);
        setProfileIcon(response.data.profileIconId);
        setLevel(response.data.summonerLevel);
        setPuuid(response.data.puuid);
        setSummonerName("");
        console.log("Hello from GetUser.jsx");
      })
      .then(() => {
        getMatchHistory(puuid);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        setError("There is no summoner with that name!");
        setSummonerName("");
        setUser("");
      });
```

Now, I chained multiple .then with simple console.log() and they displayed one after another in the correct order, but here it just doesn't work - just passes an empty string.

Comment: when you are using "then" your function would have to return something that is what will be passed in the arguments of "then". So if you want to have the uuid in the second function then callback you have to return the uuid. and then accept in the callback of second chained then callback.
Something like this.
it is just an example not the correct syntax.
request().then((res)=> return res.uuid ).then(uuid => console.log(uuid))
I have returned res.uuid which will be then passed to the chained then later and will log on to the console.

Comment: React batches state updates as a performance optimization, they do not happen instantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are accessing the puuid in your second .then() based on your code is by getting the state puuid which you set in the first .then() `setPuuid(response.data.puuid);` the problem is that the state update in react is async so at the time of accessing the state in the second .then() the state has not been updated yet.

To fix there are a few options

1. return the puuid from the first function and accept as a parameter in the second function

```
axios
      .get(`https://${region}.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/${summonerName}?api_key=${API_KEY}`)
      .then((response) => {
        setError("");
        setUser(response.data);
        setName(response.data.name);
        setProfileIcon(response.data.profileIconId);
        setLevel(response.data.summonerLevel);
        setPuuid(response.data.puuid);
        setSummonerName("");
        console.log("Hello from GetUser.jsx");
        return response.data.puuid;//return the value
      })
      .then((puuid) => {//accept it as a param
        getMatchHistory(puuid);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        setError("There is no summoner with that name!");
        setSummonerName("");
        setUser("");
      });
```

2. depending on what you are trying to do you can always move the getMatchHistory call into the first .then

```
 getMatchHistory(response.data.puuid);
```

3. have the getMatchHistory in a useEffect that runs when the puuid state is updated